# How to realize ratio with powerpivot

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to do ratio with powerpivot but I have some problem...

I have to measures : time_spent & planned_hours

There is hierarchy like this : global => project => tasks => timesheet entries

It works with timesheet entries but when I drill-up to tasks, if there is multiple timesheet entries it's sum planned_hours and make my ratio wrong...

My question, how can I for :

- timesheet entries => time_spent/planned_hours
- tasks => SUM(time_spent)/planned_hours
- project => SUM(time_spent) with tasks level / SUM(planned_hours) with task level
- global => SUM(time_spent) with projet level / SUM(planned_hours) with project level

Thanks in advance for your help :)
Arnaud

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been find !

Here is my solution, if somebody need something like that :

IF(ISFILTERED('Requête'[ID Saisie Temps]);'Requête'[Somme de Heures passées]/'Requête'[Sum of Planned_Hours];'Requête'[Somme de Heures passées]/SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Requête'; 'Requête'[Nom tâche]; "Max Heures Facturées"; MAX('Requête'[Planned_Hours]));[Max Heures Facturées]))

Best regards,
Arnaud

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).